# Vim: sync read-only status between buffer and file on disk

Tags: vim, readonly

I'm working with Perforce and all files in my client are read-only by default. So when I'm browsing the source code in vim buffers are marked read-only as well (may be this is not an accurate wording: I can edit its content but cannot save it without '!'). At some point I'm starting to do some edits and discover that I have to checkout file in Perforce. I have a 'nice' command for that:

```
command PE !p4 edit %
```

But after it finishes vim offers me a choice to either:

1. Load content from disk (which I don't want to do, because I'll lost my edits).
2. Or keep buffer as it is, but this preserves read-only mode (which I don't want either).

Of course I can change RO manually by doing `:set noro` but obviously want to avoid that.
Currently I've added it to the `PE` command above, but this doesn't check the real status of the file, so seems to be a little bit dangerous:

```
command PE !p4 edit % | set noro
```

What I really want is "true" synchronization of read-only state between file on disk and buffer in vim.

---

**UPD:** Mysteriously, the last version works out of the box -- if `p4 edit` fails RO state on buffer is not removed. No ideas how it is working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim has a `filewritable()` function to query the file's access state, why don't you use that?

```
command PE execute '!p4 edit %' | let &readonly = !filewritable(expand('%'))
```

Comment: I tried it, and now PE just results in "E34: No previous command". Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, the `:!` needs `:execute`; your attempt was wrong in that regard, too. See my edit.